# PHP Explode Funtion and Assign Data to variable (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, arrays

After Explode the .txt I have data like something 
array(1) { [0]=> string(47) "Windows Product Key Information " } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(12) "Product Name" [1]=> string(17) " Windows 10 Pro " } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "Version" [1]=> string(25) " 19041.1165 (64-bit OS) " } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "Product ID" [1]=> string(26) " **00331-10000-00001-AA555** " } 
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) " " }

and i just required the data in a variable that is in bold character help me out in this matter.

The .txt file is like

ShowKeyPlus - Windows Product Key Information

Product Name:   Windows 10 Pro

Version:    19041.1165 (64-bit OS)

Product ID: 00331-10000-00001-AA741

Comment: Farrukh, You almost get it. If you provide sample-data.txt and how you explode, its will fast for answered.

Comment: $content = fgets($file);
$carry = explode(":", $content);

Comment: This is the why I explode the file but i required the Product Id for my database to save it automatically.

Comment: and your sample-data.txt is?

Comment: what is they way to add the file here?

Comment: edit in the question please check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(!feof($file)) {
$content = fgets($file);
$carry = explode(":", $content);

if($carry[0] == "Product ID")
{
    echo $carry[1];
}

}
```

Eplaination:
Your code read it line by line.

$carry is array after your explode that line with ":"

if $carry[0] is "Product ID"
Then show the value of $carry[1]